Export List under Headings Excel
I have a spreadsheet of a personnel list.



Name
First
Last
Instrument




Bob Smith
Bob
Smith
Violin


George Strait
George
Strait
Violin


Gina Johnson
Gina
Johnson
Trumpet


Fred Weasley
Fred
Weasley
Percussion


George Weasley
George
Weasley
Percussion



The table is currently sorted instrument (custom order), Last (A to Z), First (A to Z)
I would like it to export a list (it's going into Word), and I'd really like to have it put in the heading styles I already have.  It should be again sorted instrument (custom order), Last, First, but it is displaying the name column.  Obviously there is an unequal number of players on each instrument.
VIOLIN
Bob Smith
George Strait
TRUMPET
Gina Johnson
PERCUSSION
Fred Weasley
George Weasley
Any ideas on how to make it go smoothly? I tried things like pivot tables and mail merges, but they aren't really giving me what I'm looking for.

Thanks all!  None of these are getting me what I wanted though.  When it gets over to MS Word, it needs to have the heading styles I'd like.  The Instrument has one heading style.  The names have another.  Even the space between them is its own style.
As you can probably guess, this is a program for a whole orchestra (maybe 20 instruments or so), so all of these involve me doing a whole lot of highlighting to apply the formats.  The formats are important because, once it's all on there, I may want to change all the names or instruments or spaces to a different font size to make it fit.

Have you ever used Format Painter before? It's an invaluable tool, especially in MS Word, and is probably the fastest and easiest way to apply consistent formatting to each section. All you have to do is format the first instrument/name the way you want, then use Format Painter to apply the same format to all other instruments/names. This is how I format all of my Word docs... type everything first and apply formatting later. Conditional Formatting rules could be setup in Excel, but the formatting options are limited (e.g. can't change the Font and/or Size of the headings).

Yeah, that's the highlighting I'm referring to.  Even with the info from one of the other methods, it does mean highlighting 40 sections with the format painter.  But that is (currently) saving me a little time.

The "highlighting" is little more than a mouse click in the left-hand margin to apply the same formatting in multiple places. With only 20 instruments, this would mean only 19 clicks. If you start by applying the desired formatting for the names to everything below the first instrument (including all subsequent instruments), you will only need to use Format Painter on the headings/instruments. I've edited my answer below to included additional screenshots and instructions for this...

Oh yes, I'm familiar.  I assumed putting the name format on the whole thing, but 20 highlights for the instruments, and another 20 for the spaces in between, hence the 40.
The annoying part there is how often Word decides to highlight a little extra and I get to undo it, ha ha.  But in the end, I just do this repeatedly once every few weeks, and I'm just looking for a better way.  I consider myself quite good at both programs, so it surprises me I haven't figured out a way to automate this.

Another alternative method using GROUPBY() and make sure to hit Wrap Text after the applying the formula for the selected cells:


• Formula used in cell A9
=TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(CHAR(10),REPT(CHAR(10),2)),1,
 GROUPBY(D2:D6,A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,x)),,0,-1))


CAVEAT: Since we are using TEXTJOIN() function to join multiple strings into one pack, it may hit a wall after it reaches 32767 characters. and thus return an error, it can be an array of strings or values as well, it will return an error. this goes as well with other functions that fall under Text Groups viz. ARRAYTOTEXT() or CONCAT() or CONCATENATE() etc.

Using TRIMRANGE() feature to include the entire array, which exlcudes leading or trailing empty rows
=TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(CHAR(10),REPT(CHAR(10),2)),1,
 GROUPBY(D.:.D,A.:.A,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,x)),,0,-1))


Alternatively using MAP() if one don't have access to GROUPBY():
=LET(
     a, D2:D6,
     b, UNIQUE(a),
     c, CHAR(10),
     d, MAP(b, LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(c,1,IF(x=a,A2:A6,"")))),
     TEXTJOIN(HSTACK(c,REPT(c,2)),,HSTACK(b,d)))



Well deserved upvote.

Another option for MS365 is to use some basic stack and sort logic.
First, generate a UNIQUE list of instruments in UPPER-case, if desired. Then, VSTACK the unique list on top of the range of names, as well as an array of empty strings ("") the same height as the unique list below the range of names. Lastly, SORTBY the "Unique ID" number generated with XMATCH on a similarly VSTACKed array of instruments (unique list, complete list, unique list).
=LET(
    a, D2:D6,
    u, UPPER(UNIQUE(a)),
    SORTBY(VSTACK(u,A2:A6,IF({1},"",u)),XMATCH(VSTACK(u,a,u),a))
)

To export the results to Word, first select the entire spill range (press Ctrl+Shift+8 (asterisk) if the active cell is within the range) and press Ctrl+C to copy.

Then, in Word go to Paste > Keep Text Only (or press Alt+H+V+T).

Next, select everything below the first heading/instrument and apply the desired formatting for the names (e.g. Arial, Bullets, Spacing After: 0pt). Don't worry about the subsequent instruments being included... they will be dealt with in the next step.

Select the first instrument by single-clicking next to it in the left-hand margin, then apply the desired format (e.g. Arial Black, Size: 14, Spacing After: 6pt). Then, double-click the Format Painter icon to toggle it on (and keep it on), so you can apply the same formatting in multiple places.

Lastly, single-click in the left-hand margin, next to each of the subsequent headings/instruments, to apply the same formatting. When you are finished, single-click the Format Painter icon again to toggle it off.

With only 20 or so headings, the entire process from start to finish should take 30-60 seconds or less, depending on user proficiency.

@rotabor I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. My output includes the same data in the same order as the OP's desired output, and there is no mention of filtering. The only thing missing is formatting, which is easiest to achieve in MS Word using Format Painter.

@rotabor Thanks for the suggestion, but respectfully, I disagree. Personally, I would do all formatting in Word (quickly with Format Painter). Your "Demo" also appears to be manually formatted. Conditional Formatting rules could be setup in Excel without the need for helper columns, but they are limited in their formatting options (e.g. can't change the Font and/or Size of the headings).

@rotabor Format Painter would only need to be used on the headings (instruments). I would start by formatting all data, including headings, with the desired format for the names (e.g. font, size, line spacing, bullets, etc.). Then, I would format the first heading the way I want, select it by clicking in the left-hand margin, double-click the Format Painter icon, single-click the left-hand margin beside every other heading (would take seconds only), then single-click the Format Painter icon again to turn it off. Don't get me wrong, your suggestion has merit, it's just not how I would do it.

Ok, up to you. Anyway, your solution deserves upvote.

If you have Excel 365 you could use the following formula (make sure that "wrap text" option is ticked in the cell with the formula):
=LET(
    data, A2:D6,
    instruments, UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,4)),
    names, BYROW(instruments, LAMBDA(inst, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, FILTER(INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,4) = inst)))),
    result, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10) & CHAR(10), TRUE, BYROW(instruments, LAMBDA(inst, inst & CHAR(10) & TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, FILTER(INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,4) = inst))))),
    result
)



The names variable is not needed, am I missing something?

I think I left it there accidently from an earlier version of the formula.

I thought so...

Yeah, it's in there because that's the list the personnel manager gives me.  I added the next two, used text to columns (space delimited) to separate the first and last for sorting.  I keep the initial column for cross-checking (double last name or a middle name or something).

While @MayukhBhattacharya provided the sophisticated formula which perfectly works, the simple pivot table goodly gives the desired result:

I guess no explanation is required.

Following recent comments I can recommend you the next solution:

[A2 and fill down]=IF(E2<>E1,E2,"")

You can format 'A' and 'B' as required and paste these two columns into the Word document.
The source sorting keeps.

If you need a single column only, I can propose you the modified @DjC's solution:
=LET(
  a,D2:D6,
  u,UPPER(UNIQUE(a)),
  SORTBY(VSTACK("="&u,A2:A6,REPT(u,0)),XMATCH(VSTACK(u,a,u),a))
)

It allows you to select all instruments or names at ones to apply formatting.

Steps to complete:

Copy/paste values.
Add the header and apply autofilter.
Filter "Begins With =".
Apply formatting.
Filter "Does Not Contain =".
Apply formatting.
Search for "=" and replace by "".


It's field's option to keep the source sort. It means you can manually sort the source table by the custom order. This order will be followed in the pivot table.

This was one I tried.  Despite the "Keep source sort" option checked, it was putting the names in alphabetical order by first name (it was keeping the custom instrument sorting).  I suppose I should have picked different names in this example, you can't tell here!
Unfortunately, it still was not solving my formatting problems (see comment I added to question).

More solutions added.

How is it going?
